# Why does Tkinter clock stop after 10 seconds?

Tags: python, tkinter

Digital clock is running based on system time. But after 10 seconds it stops.

Before this you can even see that the last 'tick' is 2 seconds instead of 1 second. That means it slows down somehow.
Why does it happen?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')

tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabs.pack()

clock_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)
timer_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)
stopwatch_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)
alarm_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)
international_time_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(clock_tab, text='Clock')
tabs.add(timer_tab, text='Timer')
tabs.add(stopwatch_tab, text='Stopwatch')
tabs.add(alarm_tab, text='Alarm')
tabs.add(international_time_tab, text='International time')

def time():
    time_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    date_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    time_label.config(text = time_str)
    time_label.after(1000, time)
    date_label.config(text = date_str)
    date_label.after(1000, time)

time_label = Label(root,font = ('calibri', 20))
time_label.pack()
date_label = Label(root,font = ('calibri', 15))
date_label.pack()

exit_btn = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text = 'Exit',
    command = lambda: root.quit()
        )
exit_btn.pack(fill = 'x')

def exit_func(event):
    root.quit()
root.bind('<Return>', exit_func)

time()
mainloop()
```

Comment: "Before this you can even see that the last 'tick' is 2 seconds instead of 1 second." - Where is the sample output? Also, it's not a good practice to name identifiers after module names('time' in this case)

Comment: @Vijay, how can I add a sample output if to see it you need to run the file and look how the time is going?

Comment: Am not sure why it's it make hang, but if you replace the two `after()` call in the `time()` function with a single call to `root.after(1000, time)` at the very end (you only need call it once and the widget used doesn't matter) it will keep it from stopping (as well as skipping a "tick").

Comment: I think I now know what's wrong with using the two `after()` calls: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72670310/355230) to the question [Clock with date and time in tkinter hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670149/clock-with-date-and-time-in-tkinter-hangs).

Comment: Did you follow the same college or tutorial or something like that? The code is almost identical, and contains exactly the same bug...

Comment: @wovano Indeed, I followed a few tutorials but now I can't find which contains the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `root.mainloop`. Btw, when I typed time period, I didn't get any `intellisense`. There is no `intellisense`. But I can see `intellisense` in my example.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import time
 
def timing():
    current_time = time.strftime("%H : %M : %S")
    clock.config(text=current_time)
    clock.after(200,timing)
 
root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
clock=Label(root,font=("times",60,"bold"),bg="blue")
clock.grid(row=2,column=2,pady=25,padx=100)
timing()

root.mainloop()
```